# Checking if a date in JS is 3 year ago or more

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I'm trying to figure out how to compare two dates in Typescript. I have the user inputted date:

```
const oldestDateString = this.address[0].since + '-01';
const oldestDate = new Date(oldestDateString);
```

And the date that's three years in the past (36 months):

```
const threeYearsAgo = new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 36);
```

So I go to compare these as below:

```
if (oldestDate >= threeYearsAgo) {
      // Do Something
    }
```

But I get an error on the comparison:

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'number'.
```

What I don't get is why one of them is a number, surely they should both be dates? Is there any way I can compare these two or output them in a format that matches? It doesn't have to be a typescript solution I don't mind even using vanilla JS.

I just don't want to use momentJS as this particular function in moment doesn't appear to work on some iPhones.

Old momentJS Script for reference:

```
const oldestDate = this.address[0].since + '-01';
    const months = moment().diff(moment(oldestDate), 'month', true);
    if (months >= 36) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: `const threeYearsAgo = new Date();threeYearsAgo.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 36);` you get a number because `setMonth` returns a number

Answer (score 0):

`setMonth` returns a number, not a date. TS is picky about that. Compare the date you called that set function on instead.

```
const threeYearsAgo = new Date();
threeYearsAgo.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 36);
```

Comment: This works on desktop but not on iPhone for some reason

Answer (score 0):

It's because you aren't saving a date in `threeYearsAgo`, you are saving the return value of `setMonth`.

[Date.setMonth Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth#return_value)

> **Return value**
> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date.

So you want

```
const threeYearsAgo = new Date();
threeYearsAgo.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 36)
```

Comment: This works on desktop but not on iPhone for some reason

Comment: Just tested it in Safari on iOS 12 and it works fine. It's likely something else. What error are you getting on iPhone?

Comment: My guess is that it's either something about the ts compilation settings, or the use of `this.address`, since `this` can often be weird